# Как заполнить массив данными из файла

Tags: массивы, файлы, c++

Допустим есть файл со следующим содержанием

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Я хочу написать программу, которая бы создавала массив 3х3 и заполняла его числами из файла (первая цифра - размер массива)

Помогите решить эту проблему. 
Вот мой нерабочий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "File not found\n";
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }
    int size;
    in >> size;
    cout << "size = " << size << "\n";
    int** arr = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[size];
    char c = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; c != EOF; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; c != '\n'; j++)
        {
            if (c == ' ')
                do
                {
                    c = in.get();
                } while (c == ' ');

            arr[i][j] = c - '0';
            cout << arr[i][j];
            _getch();
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Он выводит -38 а потом зацикливается

Comment: а массив нужен статический или динамический? матрица будет с разными размерами?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/208522

http://hashcode.ru/questions/202681

Comment: И кстати, вы пишете на C, пишите на C++.

Замените массивы на вектор и воспользуйтесь getline.

Comment: В каком это месте я пишу на С? Потому что не использую вектор? Так во-первых я хочу сам разобраться, как туда вводить, во-вторых я с вектором работать не умею, в третьих я потому и спрашиваю, что не знаю как это - "воспользуйтесь getline". В чем ошибка конкретно тут?

Comment: @vascus: да, на C++ предпочтительными структурами данных являются `std::vector<Т>` и `std::[w]string`. Кроме того, вы разбираете посимвольный ввод "вручную", что может быть интересно в качестве упражнения, но очень редко является правильным решением в production-коде.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вас интересует в чем именно ошибка, приводящая к зацикливанию, то вот, простейшая же ошибка.

Первый же символ после `3` в input.txt это `\n` (а не пробел **и не цифра**, которые Вы ожидаете).

Далее от кода ньюлайна Вы отнимаете код ascii 0 и получаете -38 (а ожидали '1' - '0' == 1).

Потом выходите из внутреннего `for (...; c != '\n'; ...`, а вот из внешнего `for` Вам уже не выйти, т.к. переменная **`c`** нигде больше не меняется (во внутренний `for` Вы больше не попадете, т.к. значение переменной **`c` перед ним == '\n` !!!**).

Вот и зацикливание.

Откровенно, отлаживать эту мутоту с посимвольным вводом мне сейчас совершенно не хочется.

Для получения желаемого результата можно Ваши циклы переписать вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; in.good() && i < size; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    in >> arr[i][j];
    cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
  }
  cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Как-то просто оно все оказалось, спасибо

Тогда еще дополнительный вопрос - как заставить оператор >> считывать символ '\n'? Я когда гуглил не мог именно это найти. Или если я например хочу другой спец символ считать или пробел, это возможно сделать через >> ?

Comment: @vacsus, при вводе оператором `>>` в `char` "пробельные" символы "глотаются".

Попробуйте

      cout << "try cin >>\n";
      while (cin.good()) {
        cin >> c;
        cout << "c=[" << c << "]\n";
      }
      cout << "Bye!\n";

Лично я вообще предпочитаю ввод-вывод из Си (printf/scanf/getchar/..., и особенно GNU getline()), он как-то прозрачней для понимания.

Comment: @avp: `getline` [вроде](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) [бы](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) часть стандарта.

Comment: @VladD, ну, этих гетлайнов, как в Бразилии диких обезьян...

В C++ свой getline, в glibc (или как она там?) своя getline(), а у меня раньше (еще до гнусной) была в разных \*nix-ах своя (очень похожая, только позволяла строки с продолжениями через `\\n` читать).

Пришлось переименовать.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если так как Вы хотите (чтобы разобраться), то вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    if (in == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! File not found!" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    int size;
    in >> size;

    int** arr = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[size];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            in >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "size = " << size << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вы как-то по хитрому читаете сам массив, хотя его размер читаете нормально. Не стал разбираться где там ошибка.

А вообще, как и сказал [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), если вы пишете на C++, то используйте прелести STL и замените массивы на векторы. И ссылки Вам привели хорошие, где данные считываются буквально одной строкой.

Comment: И вам тоже спасибо.